# Launching & Closing Steam Big Picture with Xbox360 Controller

Tags: autohotkey

I'm very new to this program and haven't really worked on many scripts so I'm not sure where to begin. What I need to do is set hotkeys for my Xbox360 controller that when held (for 3 seconds) launches Steam Big Picture and then while that program is running and the key is held (for 3 seconds) Big Picture will close, if not currently in a game.

[This script](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/bigpicture/discussions/1/882960163772490356/) does half of what I want it to do...

```
#IfWinNotExist, Steam ahk_class CUIEngineWin32
Joy7::
Process, Exist, Steam.exe
if ErrorLevel
Run, "steam://open/bigpicture"
else
Run, "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -bigpicture
```

The only thing I want changed to it is:

- Joy7 to be changed to the Xbox360 "X" / Guide Button
- Joy7 (or above key) held for 3 seconds
- Hold key for 3 seconds while in Big Picture (and not in a game) to
  close/return to desktop

Any ideas of how to do this? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have an Xbox controller handy, so I won't be able to help you out with the guide button. [KeyHistory](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyHistory.htm) or following the [Special Keys section](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) in the docs may be able to help you out.

The following code should put you well on your way for the other items.  Let me know if you have questions.

```
#SingleInstance force
Joy7::
    keyDown := A_TickCount
    KeyWait, %A_ThisHotkey%
    If ((A_TickCount-keyDown) > 3000)
    {

        If ProcExists("Steam.exe")
        {
            If WinActive("ahk_exe Steam.exe")
            {
                Process, Close, Steam.exe
                Sleep 50
                Send #d
            }
            Else
                Run, "steam://open/bigpicture"
        }
        Else
            Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" ;-bigpicture
    }
Return

ProcExists(p) 
{    
    Process, Exist, % p
    Return    ErrorLevel
}
```